# toll cost for my trip

Tags: usa, planning, driving, tolls

I want to find the cost of all my tolls and estimate on total gas for my trip from Mexico, ME to Chittenango, NY which is 385 miles shortest distance driving a 17 foot U-Haul truck, averaging roughly 10 miles to the gallon.

Comment: 385 miles from Mexico to New York?????  Tolls could be $0

Comment: @Karlson, Mexico, ME is the city of Mexico in the State of Maine, not the country of Mexico

Comment: Your question, as asked, could be answered by simply plugging your two points into Google Maps and then going to the states involved to see what their toll rates are (ie, any answer that you get here would simply be outsourced basic research).

Comment: A better question might be: is it safe or reasonable to drive a U-Haul truck on a route that follows US-4 through Vermont to NY-22 to US-20? Or should I stick to the interstate all the way?

Comment: @Tom my comment was left before Mark Mayo made a change to Mexico, ME.

Comment: The shortest distance route doesn't include _any_ toll roads!

Answer (score 4):

You could use websites such as [cost2drive](https://beta.costtodrive.com/us-tolls/).